# Does SubtleCrypto API support in one algorithm encryption and signing together?

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, rsa

I study the whole day [the documentation of SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) at Mozilla and was not able to find a way to do encryption and signing at the same time with one version of an RSA key.

I'am confused because I was able to write [code in Java to do this job](https://gist.github.com/blaubaer/1c6074bc674348249ab43710554f1ee4). Does Java here crazy stuff, does I not find the right way or is it just not implemented in the SubtleCrypto?

Comment: Your questions lacks specifics. There is `SubtleCrypto.encrypt()`, and `SubtleCrypto.sign()`. Now, what isn't working for you?

Comment: Yes, it's crazy, because you should not use the same key for different tasks. This might leak enough information that you lose both confidentiality as well as authentication. Use separate key pairs. Anyway, I don't know what the problem is. You can request multiple usages for `generateKey` and `importKey`. Keep in mind that encryption is done with the public key and signing with the private key.

Comment: I can't bring any code with `SubtleCrypto` to work where with one generated RSA key works for `SubtleCrypto.encrypt()`and `SubtleCrypto.sign()` at the same time, like my Java-Code does. RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5`` only works with `sign+verify` and fails with error message `DOMException: Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.` if I use `encrypt+decrypt`or `encrypt+decrypt+sign+verify`. If I do this with `RSA-OAEP` this only works with `encrypt+decrypt`but not with `sign+verify` or with `encrypt+decrypt+sign+verify`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some asymmetric algorithms will leak details about them, depending on how they are used. For this reason, the Webcrypto authors decided to "help keep users from hurting themselves" by preventing this.

Not all algorithms have this property, for example, ones based on EC-Schnorr do not (Curve25519 is such an example) that said this is not an algorithm supported by Web Crypto at this time.

It is possible to export a key and re-import it as another type, this does work around this restriction for exportable keys. That said you should use a unique key and cryptographically bind them to the same subject instead of using one key if you are using secp256r1 or its family members.